# Sum and subtract from another relation table in one query

Tags: mysql, doctrine

I have two tables, one is called **Attendance** and the other is called **Timeslices**, I am trying to get the total **seconds of Attendances subtracted from Timeslices** for the current week and also with `Doctrine`.
I've got to get the rows but I have to sum and subtract each of them out of the query, but I need to learn to do it in one query.

This is the structure of the **Attendance** Table:

```
SELECT * FROM attendance;
+----+---------+---------------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | day                 | status | check_in            | check_out           |
+----+---------+---------------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2019-12-18 00:00:00 | end    | 2019-12-18 09:52:00 | 2019-12-18 23:37:02 |
|  2 |       1 | 2019-12-19 00:00:00 | end    | 2019-12-19 12:12:00 | 2019-12-19 21:05:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**Timeslice** table:

```
SELECT * FROM timeslice;
+----+---------------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | attendance_id | title                               | day                 | start_at            | stopped_at          |
+----+---------------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 20 |             1 | Sacar al perro, ducharme y vestirme | 2019-12-18 00:00:00 | 2019-12-18 15:57:50 | 2019-12-18 12:15:36 |
| 21 |             1 | Dormir                              | 2019-12-18 00:00:00 | 2019-12-18 18:44:30 | 2019-12-18 16:16:44 |
| 22 |             1 | Descansar                           | 2019-12-18 00:00:00 | 2019-12-18 23:04:53 | 2019-12-18 20:56:29 |
| 23 |             2 | Comer                               | 2019-12-19 00:00:00 | 2019-12-19 16:03:00 | 2019-12-19 15:37:00 |
| 24 |             2 | Comer                               | 2019-12-19 00:00:00 | 2019-12-19 16:55:00 | 2019-12-19 16:17:00 |
| 25 |             2 | ducharme                            | 2019-12-19 00:00:00 | 2019-12-19 19:58:00 | 2019-12-19 17:20:00 |
+----+---------------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

This is my current **query** in which I get the results, but then I have to calculate out of the query to get the desired result and `SQLFiddle`:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/646be/3

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.check_out, a.check_in))) AS secondsAttendance
     , ( SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t.start_at, t.stopped_at))) 
           FROM timeslice t 
          WHERE t.attendance_id = a.id
       ) secondsPauses 
  FROM attendance a 
 GROUP 
    BY a.id
```

What I need as I said before is to be able to do it in the same query without having to use PHP and with `Doctrine`

Comment: Can you edit the question to show, using formatted text (not pictures), what the final desired result should look like

Comment: I also think it's weird that you have no way of knowing which result belongs to which id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed my answer after your comments. If you only need the value it seams that all you need to do is to use you initial query (with a few twicks) as a 
subquery in the FROM clause ([Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)) and then, do your calculations over it. In this case simply need to SUM the result of subtracting the secondsPauses to the secondsAttendance, like this:

```
-- make the calculation you need over the results
SELECT SUM(Results.secondsAttendance - Results.secondsPauses) as ActualValue
FROM ( 
  -- use you initial results as a subquery and name it as Results
  SELECT 
  SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.check_out, a.check_in))) AS secondsAttendance, 
  (SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t.start_at, t.stopped_at))) 
  FROM timeslice t WHERE t.attendance_id = a.id) AS secondsPauses 
  FROM attendance a 
  -- filter date for the current week 
  where yearweek(DATE(a.check_in), 1) = yearweek(curdate(), 1) 

  GROUP BY a.id
) Results;
```

The result is:

```
+-------------+
| ActualValue |
+-------------+
| 38258       |
+-------------+
```

[SqlFiddle in here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/646be/23/0)

Comment: Thank you, but it's not correct, it multiplies the results when you do the left join or I think that's what happens.

Comment: Hy @jcarlosweb, I've tested using your fiddler data, are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The total of seconds that should show is 38258, this is your http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/646be/7, if you sum the currentSecondaAttendace, it is not correct, besides that it show multiple results. This is my http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/646be/3, which is correct if you sum the multiple results of secondsAttendance and subtract secondsPauses, but as I said in my question I have to do the calculations outside the query, and I need to learn to do it in one query.

Comment: Yes @jcarlosweb, you are right. Sorry my bad. I've just edited my answer.

Comment: Awesome! It would be ideal if you could explain what you've done, especially about `FROM () N;` which is the first time I've seen it.

Comment: Glad it helped! (finally). I've re edited the answer, with more detail and the fiddler to. If this worked for you can you please "accept" the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time, I will read the link you put on Derived Tables, because it is the first time I see this :)